# Connecting with SMB from Mac to Windows server

Tags: windows, mac-osx, server-message-block

I'm trying to connect from my Mac to a directory on a Windows server.

Here is what I'm doing from the finder :
menu `Go->connect to server->smb://srv-fichiers1/Personnel/conujer`

I get an error (error code -36).

But, from the finder window, if I click on `Shared->All->srv-fichier1->Personnel->conujer`, I have access to the directory.

[image]

I don't understand why I cannot connect straight to `conujer`.

Comment: Can you connect to `smb://srv-fichiers1/Personnel` and then navigate to the conujer subfolder?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson : yes I can.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using different or saved credentials when using the file share than your own? (http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20949?viewlocale=en_US)

Are there any error messages showing up in the logs?

What version OS X and Windows are being used? And with or without active directory?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the 10.4 article on -36

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1564?viewlocale=en_US

That however doesnt look like it will solve your issue, but this might.

http://www.macyourself.com/2010/01/07/solution-to-finder-error-code-36-in-10-6-when-copying-folders/

According to that 10.6.3 patch has fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my Mac here with me now, but have you tried adding a following slash to the path?  So:

```
Go->connect to server->smb://srv-fichiers1/Personnel/conujer/
```